# Macro freezing in Do While Loop

Tags: vba

I have ~30 worksheets in my workbook and i want to make some action with worksheets, which located between my flags (Start and End).
But some times (~80% chance) my macro freeze (Not Responding status) in the loop. Sometimes i can break it, press "debug", press F5 and macro correctly ended. It works correctly, if i make breakpoint at the start of the loop and press F5 each cycle. But if i Run macro w/o breakpoints - its freeze
Why it's happening? How i can optimize my code?

This is my code

```
Sub DataPreparation()
Dim ws As Worksheet

ClearData

rowToEnter = 2
Worksheets("Start").Activate
Do While Not Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Name Like "End*"
    If ActiveSheet.Visible = True Then
        Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Activate
        *SOME PROCEDURES*
    End If
Loop

DeleteEmptyRows

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't really know VBA, but it seems if ActiveSheet.Visible is not true, the content of your loop becomes empty and you loop won't make any progress.

Comment: Oh, thank u!  I'm use  "Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Activate" outside IF and all starts work better. But why it works normal in "manual mode" (when i make breakpoint at the start of the loop) before?

Comment: How i can mark you comment as Answer?

Comment: I made the comment an answer so you can upvote/accept it if you wish. Regarding your additional question in the comment: Maybe your interaction with the debugger made the sheet visible, thereby allowing the loop to proceed again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you do in your loop is inside

```
If ActiveSheet.Visible = True Then
    Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Activate
    *SOME PROCEDURES*
End If
```

So when the condition is not true the loop does nothing and therefore never progresses.

Probably the correct thing to do is to move the `Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Activate` before the if condition.